# Standard button highlight on hover disappears on border style changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/an5fg5t2/

```css
.differentbutton {
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid DarkGrey;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  standard
</button>

<button class="differentbutton">
  Different
</button>
```

All I did was add a couple styles so IE buttons would look the same as FF chrome and safari.  However that change caused the highlight on hover to disappear.  Removing all styles and adding them one by one means the border declarations cause the highlight on hover to not work.

My searches yielded complex problems for other platforms.  Is there any documentation that supports this behavior?  How can I keep this behavior with modifications?

Comment: Can't see what the issue is, There is no :hover element on the code here or the fiddle?

Comment: @Ricky Hover your mouse over the buttons on the fiddle.  One highlights and the other does not.  Read the last question How can I keep this behavior with modifications?

Comment: Got to agree with Ricky-- I hovered both buttons in the fiddle and got no hover state for either.

Comment: @anied I get a light blue background color change to light blue when my mouse is over the button labeled standard.  There may be not hover declared.  However the standard button does change to light blue when my mouse hovers over it without a :hover declaration

Comment: I only get that if you click a button, however look at my answer

Comment: @user1015711-- what browser are you using?  This may be something in the browser stylesheet only, that isn't preset in other browsers.

Comment: @anied  I will double check that

Comment: This is likely OS- and browser-dependent. IE adds a flat, light blue background effect when hovering over a plain button element. Firefox adds a gradient light blue background. Chrome appears to make the button's border slightly thicker.

Answer (score 1):

To get it to Highlight when you hover over, you need to add the following bit of CSS to your code:

```
.differentbutton:hover {
  border: 1px solid Grey;
}
```

If you add it underneath the class .differentbutton, then when you hover over the button it will "highlight" the button for you, change the colour as you see fit.

Comment: Its the light blue highlight on hover that I am after.

Comment: As i said change the colour as you see fit, do you know how to change colour values with hex/RGB?

Comment: then you can change the css property/value between the brackets to something like `border: 2px solid lightblue;` or something similar.  However, if you specifically want the `outline` property, things will get a little more complex cross-browser.

Comment: Perhaps capture and add a screenshot of exactly what it is you are seeing that you are after?

Comment: Far easier + quicker to just change the border color on hover, alot less hassle and it will all look the same cross browser.

Comment: @Ricky-- yeah, I don't disagree-- just trying to get a sense of what it is he or she is trying to reproduce exactly.

Comment: Well, what i get on their fiddle, is when i hover on both buttons nothing happens, if i click on both buttons, nothing happens on the "standard" but the "different" gets a light blue outline as shown here: https://i.imgsafe.org/55105593b9.png, which is kind of backwards by the looks of things